confirmSignUp in aws amplify not recognizing verification code
I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going wrong when passing the verification code to confirmSignUp in vue. Here is the code:
const username = this.email;
        const code = this.verificationCode;
        console.log('Username passed to confirmSignUp:', username);
        console.log('Verification code passed to confirmSignUp:', code);
        await confirmSignUp({
          username: username,
          code: code,
        });

The console logs are printing the correct information to be passed to the function, but the function throws this error:
Error verifying code: EmptyConfirmSignUpCode: code is required to confirmSignUp
    at assertValidationError 

I've tried passing the parameters as separate objects, but the documentation seems to imply a single object is required and the username is not recognized when passing separate objects. I've tried referencing the code from the input field directly, none of it makes a difference. I'm convinced something is wrong with the amplify setup or function call itself because like I said, the correct values are logged to console, then the function call is just not seeing them. FWIW, this is the same way I've been calling other amplify functions and this is the only one that refuses to work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The correct parameter is confirmationCode, not code, this resolved the issue
